# Timestamps are wrong for editing "answers" which were converted to comments by a moderator

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, answers

I noticed the following on http://tex.stackexchange.com where I'm a moderator:

Answers can be converted to comments to the question (or to another answer) by a moderator. However, the creation date of the comment is the last-modified date of the answer, not the original creation date of it.

If the **comments to that answer** are also moved to the same post, they keep their original date and **can appear before the answer** that was converted to a comment, which makes things quite confusing to read and AFAIK can break `@` notification.

#### Example:

Imagine a (non-)answer which was edited after it received comments and is then converted to a comment below another answer including its own comments:

**Before:**

```
Answer 1 (real answer)


Answer 2 (actually a comment to Answer 1) [Created e.g. at 10:00am, edited 10:04am]
  `-- Comment 2-1 [Created e.g. at 10:01am]
  `-- Comment 2-2 [Created e.g. at 10:05am]
```

**After:**

```
Answer 1 (real answer)
  `-- Comment 1-1: Was Comment 2-1 [Created e.g. at 10:01am]
  `-- Comment 1-2: Was Answer 2    [Created e.g. at 10:00am, edited 10:04am]
  `-- Comment 1-3: Was Comment 2-2 [Created e.g. at 10:05am]
```

Now the first comment refers to a comment below it (which lost its history), and this can be very confusing for people.

**The correct order would be:**

```
Answer 1 (real answer)
  `-- Comment 1-1: Was Answer 2    [Created e.g. at 10:00am, edited 10:04am]
  `-- Comment 1-2: Was Comment 2-1 [Created e.g. at 10:01am]
  `-- Comment 1-3: Was Comment 2-2 [Created e.g. at 10:05am]
```

Could you please change the implementation so that converted comments are generated with the *original creation date* of the answer they come from. They could be marked as edited if the answer was ever edited.

Comment: I was going to enter a bug report, but I think it's a consequence of this one: when an answer A is converted into a comment on an answer B, it enters B's author's global inbox at the date of answer A. If B's author has flushed his inbox since then, the reply is already marked as read by the time it appears, so B's author will effectively not be notified. [Example.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/how-to-overwrite-target-files-with-mv/9912#comment-15578)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in latest,

Comment now has the same date the post was created and will be marked edited if it was edited.

Comment: to be deployed today